# How to add a widget after post content

Tags: wordpress, widget

Right now in my theme for my home page I have a row of 1 post, a row of 3 posts, 3 posts, and then back to a row of 1 post.  After this loop I would like to add a new widget.  I want to have a few different widgets like popular videos, popular posts, etc.  Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Here is an example of what I want it to look like.  I want a new widget for every 14 posts.

[image]

Here is are some examples of the different widgets I want to add (source - http://www.whowhatwear.com) -

[image]

[image]

Here is my front-page.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: learningwordpress
 */
 
get_header();
 get_template_part ('inc/carousel');
$i = 0;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => 1
);
 
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 
        if( $i %2 == 1 ) {
                   $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>

 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php

        }
        else {
         $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-12">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
get_footer();
```

Comment: i think [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-widget-after-content/screenshots/) will help

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your theme functions.php file to create widget

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'After content',
        'id'            => 'after-content',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
```

Add following code where you want to display widget area

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'after-content' ) ) : 
    dynamic_sidebar( 'after-content' );
endif;
```

Comment: What if I want to display a widget in the same spot every time but I want to use like 5 different widgets.  Would the above code still work?